# PHP: is it possible to convert a mysqli error number into a mysqli error?

Tags: php, function, mysqli

I have two different php pages. The first page is using mysql(i) and the second not. Since I use php `header()` function to go to the second page, I can only pass `$_GET[]` variables to the second page. These variables can have a limited value. I wanted to send the mysqli error, if there is one, to the second page, but using `mysqli_error` I have a very large string. I was wondering if it is possible to use `mysqli_errno`, which gives me a number which isn't that large, and convert it on the second page with a php function to a `mysqli_error` string. It would save me a lot of work instead of making lines of code to cover all possible errors.
I have searched in several search engines for converting `mysqli_errno` into `mysqli_error`, but I could only find converting mysql into mysqli.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By using `mysqli_error()` <--Just going with title

Comment: You could store the string returned by `mysqli_error()` in the session instead of passing it via a get param. That is assuming both pages run on the same server.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I'm not familiar with English, so I don't understand what you mean with: _Just going with title_

Comment: @D-Inventor I commented, by just reading your question's title, as I didn't read the questions body

Comment: I think Raphael Schweikerts answer works the easiest for you. If you want to have a Number-To-Errorstring function check the manual:
`Client error message numbers are listed in the MySQL errmsg.h header file, server error message numbers are listed in mysqld_error.h. In the MySQL source distribution you can find a complete list of error messages and error numbers in the file Docs/mysqld_error.txt.`

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant solution, but you could

Page 1

1. Pass the error number to page 2 as a URL parameter.

Page 2

1. Pick up the error number with $_GET
2. If the error number isn't 0, re-run the query and use `mysqli_error` to get the string.